# How to add list of items in toolbar setting button?

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have created one toolbar with three things in it.

- User Avataar
- Title
- ic_action_overflow

I want to add some list of items in ic_action_overflow.When user clicks on this list of drop down should get open.

Please find the activity.xml for reference :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.vimal.edkul.StudentProfile">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/red">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/pic13" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="User Profile"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can add Spinner instead of Image view (ie `ic_action_overflow`)

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-action-items-and-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android/

Comment: @Kathi Thanks.It is good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect tutorial for adding items on toolbar overflow icon:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-action-items-and-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android/

You can also try with this tutorial :

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_Overflow_Menus_on_Android

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    Toolbar toolbr = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.some_menu);
    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        toolbar.getMenu().add(items[i]);
    }
```